# sbt-rjs: Exclude files from uglification

Tags: requirejs, sbt, uglifyjs, sbt-web

I'm using [sbt-rjs](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-rjs) with the [sbt-web](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web) pipeline to minify and concatenate my javascripts in the the build process. Part of this is uglifying the files which is handled by rjs with the default *uglify2* optimiser.

My questing is if I can exclude files from the uglification but still include them in the concatenated module? In particular I want to skip the already minified files, in order to shorten the build time.

Comment: this is a good question. did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: @Ophelia I couldn't find a solution. I the meantime I actually dropped the use of sbt-rjs. I now just use [sbt-uglify](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-uglify) directly which at least gives me an `includeFilter in uglify := ...`. That, together with the aggressive caching provided by the sbt-digest module actually resulted in an overall better performance than a merged js file and an improved build time. This might be a particularity of this project though, as I do change scripts very often and even a tiny edit would trigger the re-download of the huge merged file.